# How can I see all the SQL queries that are being ran on each page load?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Django has a debug toolbar that lets me see all the queries being ran, how can I view them in MVC4?

Comment: That means you want know what is the sql statement used by EDM to process your request?

Comment: @JayantVarshney: Yes. I want to make sure it's not doing more queries than it needs to, or making them more complex than they need to be.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see just executed SQL commands you can use IntelliTrace (only available in VS Ultimate edition). If you want to have per request profiling you can try [MVC Mini Profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/). EF doesn't have any built-in tool for tracking executed SQL commands.

Comment: Just installed it from NuGet, I think this version is broken. It asks for a file `ProfiledDbConnection.cs` located at `C:\Users\sam\Desktop\MiniProfiler\StackExchange.Profiling\Data\ProfiledDbConnection.cs` (I'm not Sam). Edit: Found this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144061/miniprofiler-nullreferenceexception-in-sqlserverstorage-loadinbatch-function-d

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a number of tools that you can consider. I discuss a number of these at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Database-Performance-hints including Intellitrace, and SQL Profiler, and other relatively inexpensive profiling tools out there like the MVC MiniProfiler, ORM Profiler,  Huagati’s LINQ to SQL Profiler, EF Prof, or at a bare minimum checking the generated code for your queries using LinqPad. Some of these options require you to modify your existing code base to plug in the profiler. Others just intercept the traffic to the database. It doesn't really matter which one you use as long as you use something particularly while you are learning.

Answer (score 1):

Oks, let us take an example of northwind database

```
using(NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities())
{
   var query = from p in context.Products
               where p.Product_ID == 3
               select p;

   //Query can be traced like this
   var SqlQuery = (System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Product>)query;
   Console.WriteLine(SqlQuery.ToTraceString());
}
```

you can use this `var SqlQuery = (System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<Product>)query;` at your page load and can print the value wherever you want.